# Smart pointers and dependency on it in the whole program, once used

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Storage of monsters:

```
class MonstersStorage
{
  public:
    std::weak_ptr<Monster> getMonster(int ID) const;
  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Monster>> monsters;
}
```

There is only one storage of monsters in the game. There's a lot of code that uses `Monster` objects.

I made monsters' storage storing smart pointers for only one reason - sometimes there is need to temporary store reference to `Monster` in other places, and monsters can die(be deleted and be removed from storage) - thus refences must safely expire. Otherwise I would just use normal pointers.

Problem is that, in the whole game, in every place that `Monster` is used, it have to be weak pointer instead of simple reference or pointer - because all `Monster` objects comes from one source - Monsters Storage.

Even in case of functions that just need `Monster` to be passed to them and makes some operations on it but do not save reference to it. For example:

```
getDamageDealedBy(const Monster&);
```

It will have to be:

```
getDamageDealedBy(const std::weak_ptr<Monster>&);
```

It gets all code depending on monsters' storage implementation.

My question is, in case of such functions should I use just simple references, received by *.get() from smart pointer,
Or should weak_ptr be used in the whole program in case of `Monster` class.

Edited: And everytime use this .lock() functions over, and over again, to convert it to shared_ptr, while accessing monster

Answer (score 2):

There's only person who has the answer to this question. This is the person who knows exactly the scope and the lifetime of each object that's owned by the smart pointers. That would be you.

When the last `std::shared_ptr` that refers to a particular object goes out of scope, the object gets destroyed. If, based on the way your application uses those objects, this can never happen while some other part of your application is using a regular "non-smart" pointer to refer to this object, then, of course, it's fine to use only regular pointers.

For example, here's one situation you know it would be safe to use an ordinary pointer.

```
void somefunction(const std::shared_ptr<Monster> &monster_ptr)
{
    Monster *p=monster_ptr.get();

    // ... Use p inside this function
}
```

Because the `std::shared_ptr` gets passed to `somefunction()` as a parameter, and the scope of `monster_ptr` exists for the entire `somefunction()` it is safe to just use `get()` and use the returned pointer inside this function.

You know that `monster_ptr` is going to exist for the duration of this function. As such, `monster_ptr` will retain a `std::shared_ptr` reference to the underlying object, and because of that there will always be at least one smart reference to the underlying object for the duration of this function (and for the duration of any other function that's called from this function). `monster_ptr` will go out of scope only after `somefunction()` returns, and until that happens, it is guaranteed that you will have a smart reference to the underlying object, and it is safe to use a direct native pointer.

In conclusion: if you can prove that at a particular point in your application it's guaranteed that there's at least one `std::shared_ptr` referencing a given object, then it is safe to use an ordinary pointer to access this object.